# RelativeLayoutButton not working after Android Studio upgrade

Tags: android, button, android-relativelayout

i am tring to build an app that control the lights in my house.
The first version of the app is working great and looks like this:
[Old app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIEun.jpg)


But that version was build with older version of Android studio and the updated Android studio won't compile the app.
 Too many errors. So i started from scratch.
my problem is that now my app looks like this:
[new app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNqjT.jpg)


My project is located [here](https://github.com/Malikster/HomeRemote):

I do not know the section of my code that does not work properly so i will not post the entire code here.
Could someone look up at the code and help me?

Comment: Seems u have upgraded to androidx library. Check the official doc to migrate to androidx components.

Comment: the old app was made with androidx library. [Here](https://github.com/Malikster/Automatizare-Casa) is the old app located.